# What the error "Pipeline #1234 failed with stage" means on a git push?

Tags: git

We are pushing some changes to a customer on their git repository but we are blocked by receiving this message:

> "Pipeline #1234 failed with stage"

I was wondering if could be some integration on their git server that is trying to  build or test the code?
Thanks.

Comment: does the code compile on your local machine? Are there any failing unit tests?

Comment: Yes, it seems like a CI is running online (i.e., it runs immediately on push) on the server side. But hard to tell without more details. You have to ask the admins/devs at the server.

Comment: Yes, the code is fine (Unity). We can build and it works fine. Might be some integration trying to build on their side. I am waiting for them to answer if they know what is going on.